# Is there a way to handle a variable number of inputs/outputs in Nextflow?

Tags: groovy, nextflow

Is there a way to handle a varying number of inputs/outputs in Nextflow? Sometimes in the example below process 'foo' will have three inputs (and therefore create three pngs that need stitched together by 'bar') but other times there will be two or four. I'd like process 'bar' to be able to combine all existing files in 'foo.out.files' regardless of number. As it stands this would be able to properly handle everything only if there were exactly three inputs in params.input, but not if there were two or four.

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process foo {
   input:
   path input_file

   output:
   path '*.png', emit files

   """
   script that creates variable number of png files
   """
}

process bar {
   input:
   tuple path(file_1), path(file_2), path(file_3)

   """
   script that combines png files ${file_1} ${file_2} ${file_3}
   """
}

workflow {

   foo(params.input)
   bar(foo.out.files.collect())
}
```

UPDATE:
I'm getting 'Input tuple does not match input set cardinality' errors for this, for example:

```
params.num_files = 3

process foo {
   input:
   val num_files

   output:
   path '*.png', emit: files

   """
   touch \$(seq -f "%g.png" 1 ${num_files})
   """
}

process bar {
   debug true

   input:
   tuple val(word), path(png_files)

   """
   echo "${word} ${png_files}"
   """
}

workflow {
    foo( params.num_files )

    words = Channel.from('a','b','c')

    words
        .combine(foo.out.files)
        .set { combined }
    
    bar(combined)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't acutally need the `tuple` qualifier here: the `path` input qualifier can also handle a collection of files. If you use a variable or the `*` wildcard, the original filenames will be preserved. In the example below, the variable refers to all files in the list. But if you need to, you can also access specific entries; for example:

```
params.num_files = 3

process foo {
   input:
   val num_files

   output:
   path '*.png', emit: files

   """
   touch \$(seq -f "%g.png" 1 ${num_files})
   """
}

process bar {
   debug true

   input:
   path png_files

   script:
   def first_png = png_files.first()
   def last_png = png_files.last()

   """
   echo ${png_files}
   echo "${png_files[0]}"
   echo "${first_png}, ${last_png}"
   """
}

workflow {
   bar( foo( params.num_files ) )
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [mighty_solvay] DSL2 - revision: 662b108e42
executor >  local (2)
[e0/a619c4] process > foo [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[ba/5f8032] process > bar [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
1.png 2.png 3.png
1.png
1.png, 3.png
```

---

If you need to avoid potential filename collisions, you can have Nextflow rewrite the input filenames using a name pattern. If the name pattern is a simple string and a collection of files is received, the filenames will be  appended with a numerical suffix representing the ordinal position in the list. For example, if we change the 'bar' process definition to:

```
process bar {

   debug true

   input:
   path 'png_file'

   """
   echo png_file*
   """
}
```

We get:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [marvelous_bhaskara] DSL2 - revision: 980a2d067f
executor >  local (2)
[f8/190e2c] process > foo [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[71/e53b05] process > bar [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
png_file1 png_file2 png_file3


$ nextflow run main.nf --num_files 1
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [nauseous_brattain] DSL2 - revision: 980a2d067f
executor >  local (2)
[ce/2ba1b1] process > foo [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[a2/7b867e] process > bar [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
png_file
```

Note that the `*` and `?` wildcards can be used to control the names of the staged files. There is a [table](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-input-files) in the documentation that describes how the wildcards are to be replaced depending on the cardinality of the collection. For example, if we again change the 'bar' process definition to:

```
process bar {

   debug true

   input:
   path 'file*.png'

   """
   echo file*.png
   """
}
```

We get:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [small_poincare] DSL2 - revision: b106710bc6
executor >  local (2)
[7c/cf38b8] process > foo [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[a6/8cb817] process > bar [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
file1.png file2.png file3.png


$ nextflow run main.nf --num_files 1
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [friendly_pasteur] DSL2 - revision: b106710bc6
executor >  local (2)
[59/2b235b] process > foo [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[2f/76e4e2] process > bar [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
file.png
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Being able to subset the channel within the script via '${png_files[0]}' is really cool. 

What if there are other items in the channel as well though? For my current problem I've found I need to use the combine operator to run process bar on each of three other input files. I've updated the question so the code can fit. TIA!

Comment: Update: a toList() or collect() works for the example, but I needed to manually regroup my files using map to get my specific use case working. First two items are named inputs and then third to last items are the grouped files, so this worked:

`map { it -> [ it[0], it[1], it[2..-1] ] }`

Comment: @AnteMeta No worries! In the example, you could actually avoid using the [combine](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) operator altogether. Since `foo.out` is a [value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) channel, it could instead be an additional input declaration such that process bar could be called using `bar(words, foo.out)`. But maybe you actually have two queue channels in your non-example code, in which case, you'll need to combine the two channels like you've done.

Comment: @AnteMeta You could also regroup your files to get what you want using: `map { it -> tuple( *it.take(2), it.drop(2) ) }`. The only advantage here is that if the number of named inputs changes for whatever reason, then this can be altered without adding addition code. Your solution using square bracket notation is natural but also equally readable in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks so much, once again!! As you guessed, I do indeed have two queue channels. I'm just not so great at making entirely accurate examples. RE using .drop - that's super handy and I don't even see it in the nextflow docs. Guess that's my cue to spend more time on Groovy directly haha!